# How to run a PAC proxy script in Node?

Tags: node.js, proxy, http-proxy

I am trying to write a node program (suggestion for other language are welcome) that can parse and run a corporate proxy script PAC and return the appropriate proxy server to use programmatically.

Are there any existing solutions that can do this? (or is this only possible through a browser)

It seems like PAC files assume certain global functions exist in the execution context such as

```
shExpMatch()
myIpAddress() // interestingly the nodejs ip package return the true LAN DHCP assigned IP instead of a VPN IP
```

The goal is to resolve the right proxy server each time a shell is launched (or not set it at all if not behind a proxy)

any tip is greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're sticking with Node, I'd recommend using something like [pac-resolver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pac-resolver) for this.

```
const pac = require('pac-resolver');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const ip = require('ip');

fetch('http://<proxy_host>:<proxy_port>')
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(body => {
    // to handle a bug when pinging 8.8.8.8 will time out
    // see: https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-pac-resolver/issues/18
    findProxy = pac(body, { sandbox: { myIpAddress: ip.address }, });
    return findProxy('http://google.com/'));
  })
  .then(proxy => console.log(proxy))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

In any case, you can look at [the repo](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-pac-resolver) to see which global functions need to be defined and how that would be done in JavaScript.

If you can use other languages, look at [pacparser](https://github.com/manugarg/pacparser).

The list of standard global functions, by the way, is [here](https://findproxyforurl.com/pac-functions/):

- dnsDomainIs
- shExpMatch
- isInNet
- myIpAddress
- dnsResolve
- isPlainHostName
- localHostOrDomainIs
- isResolvable
- dnsDomainLevels
- weekdayRange
- dateRange
- timeRange
- alert